# How does setOffscreenPageLimit() improve ViewPager performance by retaining more offscreen Fragments?

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` controlling five `Fragments`.  When I swipe from `Fragment` at index 1 to `Fragment` at index 0, **there's a brief pause in the animation** that I'd like to eliminate.

Currently, I'm not calling `setOffscreenPageLimit()`, so I know that `Fragment` 0 is being held in memory by the `ViewPager` while I'm on `Fragment` 1 in its idle state, because the off screen page limit defaults to 1 (one on either side of the current `Fragment`).

Here's where it gets confusing.  If I call `setOffscreenPageLimit(4)` on my `ViewPager`, **the pause in the swipe from 1 to 0 animation is gone -- the animation is smooth**.

Therefore, I conclude that somehow, keeping `Fragments` 2-4 in memory improves the animation from `Fragment` 1 to `Fragment` 0.

**How does retaining `Fragments` 2-4 improve the swiping animation from `Fragment` 1 to `Fragment` 0?**

**Edit**

I ran TraceView, using `onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)` to determine when to start and stop the trace, as follows:

```
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    if (state == 1 && mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
        Debug.startMethodTracing("ViewPagerTesting", 100000000);
    }

    if (state == 0 && mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        Debug.stopMethodTracing();
    }
}
```

It appears that the `ViewPager`'s accessibility methods are causing the UI thread to freeze.  When I call `setOffscreenPageLimit(4)` on the ViewPager, these accessibility methods are way down in the trace -- taking negligible time to finish.

What's causing the delay?

[image: TraceView]

Comment: Use Traceview and find out.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have made Music app with multiple tabs in it. All tabs are integrated with ViewPager. Now, if i make its offScreenPageLimit to NUMBER OF TABS. it works great but when it also called on resume method and UI become hang. Do you have any idea. I guess my question is related to this topic that's why i have add comment here.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer: As I wrote in my comment, use Traceview and find out. Or use logging and find out.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your reply. Let me check it. and if i got stuch in that, please help me... Thanks once again.

Comment: @CommonsWare and iDoid Explorer - facing similar kind of issue - I am using viewpager with 5 pages, application works perfect with normal swipe back and front but when I use same for wireless keyboard accessibility it gets freezes at some point, I tried to add "setOffscreenPageLimit(pages.length);" it starts navigating without freezing anywhere. 
Now my point is - issue gets resolved but what makes it to get resolved? any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use the default implementation of `setOffscreenPageLimit()` it is only loading the one fragment which is to the right of it. For eg. when you are on index 1, it has index 2 loaded in memory but not index 0, so swiping left will have to generate a new fragment from scratch. To test this theory you might want to use `setOffscreenPageLimit(2)` and then try swiping index 1->0. This in no way is the optimal solution but will help clear out your doubts about the concept.

Comment: I did some thinking on my own after posting my question, and came to this conclusion as well.  The processes started in `onResume()` in fragment 2 was blocking the UI thread.  This is a bit counterintuitive -- my initial reaction was that the *pausing* of fragment 2 was causing the delay, not the *resuming*.

Comment: @Shakti Is there a way to set the fragment that goes offscreen? I have 3 fragments and the third one overlaps the second one after being called for first time, how can I avoid that?