# TabLayout with ViewPager not working as expected

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

There is 3 `TabLayout` with `ViewPager` in my application.

If I swipe for change Tabs then it **behaves strangely**.

Below is the scenario.

Let's say 3 Tabs A, B, C.

Default Tab A will open when I start App.

Go to B From A - Works OK.
Go to A From B - Works Ok.
Go To B From A - Works Ok.
Go To C From B - Works Ok.

Now Problem Starts here.
**Go To B From C - It will Load A and B Both but display Only B.**

> Why A and B loads if I come from C ??

Below is my code.

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentOpen(), "OPEN");
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentClose(), "CLOSE");
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentTest(), "TEST");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

I want to load Tabs every time.
For that, I use below code.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if(adapter != null){
                    adapter.getItem(position).onResume();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Page Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

But it will always load both tabs when I came from C.

> What I want is: only Tab B must load when came from C, not Both.

Comment: It is because of ViewPager which load data of current tab as well as next visible tab.

Comment: Your tabLayout is inside an Activity or Fragment?. adapter.getItem(position).onResume(); this is not the best way to change fragments, you should replace fragment instead.

Comment: http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/how-to-load-fragment-data-only-when-its-tab-selected/

Comment: @JonathanAste It is inside of Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible when using `ViewPager`. `ViewPager` loads at least `one` right/left `adjacent` fragment of `current` fragment as per your swipe direction.

If you read the `ViewPager` documentation, there is a method `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(LIMIT)` which supports off screen page limit and its `default` value is `1`.

**SetOffscreenPageLimit:**

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
> current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
> limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.
>
> This is offered as an optimization. If you know in advance the number
> of pages you will need to support or have lazy-loading mechanisms in
> place on your pages, tweaking this setting can have benefits in
> perceived smoothness of paging animations and interaction. If you have
> a small number of pages (3-4) that you can keep active all at once,
> less time will be spent in layout for newly created view subtrees as
> the user pages back and forth.
>
> You should keep this limit low, especially if your pages have complex
> layouts. This setting defaults to 1.

See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29).

Here are some related answers:

**1.** [ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0) doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073214/viewpager-setoffscreenpagelimit0-doesnt-work-as-expected)

**2.** [How can make my ViewPager load only one page at a time ie setOffscreenPageLimit(0);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096868/how-can-make-my-viewpager-load-only-one-page-at-a-time-ie-setoffscreenpagelimit/19097056)

**3.** [How does setOffscreenPageLimit() improve ViewPager performance by retaining more offscreen Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322207/how-does-setoffscreenpagelimit-improve-viewpager-performance-by-retaining-more)

Comment: Can you suggest any alternatives for this? I want to prevent tabs to load. If I swipe tabs, it should not load any tabs.

Comment: You can try with `Interface`. Write an `Interface` in your `activity` and implement it from `Fragment` classes.  Add addOnPageChangeListener to viewpager and setOnTabSelectedListener to TabLayout. From those listeners  implemented method call your own interface method and pass  current item position with it. Then in your fragment check weather the current item is your current fragment or not and loads data otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

> its Default behavior of `ViewPager` if you are in A then it loads B
>   also and when your reach B it will Load C and A also is Loaded now
>   when to reach at C its destroy the View of A and now when you come
>   again to B it will Load A again, in a simple way `ViewPager` Maintain
>   the One `Next` and One `previous` state of View by Default.

to Overcome this you should use `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(number)` here number is the count of page to load Simulationally for Next and Previous View.

Comment: Can you suggest any alternatives for this? I want to prevent tabs to load. If I swipe tabs, it should not load any tabs.

Comment: yes i can. as you mentioned you have 3 Tabs and you Don't want to load any one tab when you swiping these, so you have to set this ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); after this viewPager.setAdapter(adapter); statement, that's it, it will not load again when you swipe tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had only 3 tabs and setting`ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)` worked for me.

Try `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(totTabs - 1)`